# NestJS: How to access Execution context in strategy?

Tags: nestjs

I was implementing a Strategy using passport in my NestJs app.However I was facing an error "context.getHandler is not a function" in my strategy.Shouldnt the execution Context be available?

```
import { Strategy } from 'passport-custom';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { ExecutionContext, Injectable, UnauthorizedException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ModuleRef, Reflector } from '@nestjs/core';


@Injectable()

export class RolesStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'roles-strategy') {

  constructor(private readonly moduleRef: ModuleRef, private reflector: Reflector) {
    super();
  }

  async validate(req: Request, context: ExecutionContext): Promise<Object> {

    if(req.headers['authorization']) {

        const token = req.headers['authorization'];
        const roles = this.reflector.get<string[]>('roles', context.getHandler());

    } else {
       throw new UnauthorizedException();
    }
  }

}
```

My API below

```
 @ApiSecurity('key')
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard(['admin-strategy', 'roles-strategy']))
  @Roles('admin')
  @Get('/greet')
  async sayHello(@Headers() headers): Promise<any> {

    try {

      return { message: 'Hi' } ;

    } catch (error) {

      throw new InternalServerErrorException(error.message, error.status);

    }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

that's not the signature of `validate` method, see: https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authentication#implementing-passport-strategies there's no `context` on it. I don't know why you thought that. Strategies are basically just providers, not guards. The guard is that `AuthGuard`.